# How do I distinguish between a mouse click and space bar click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery-ui dialog box with a cancel button which closes the dialog. In this dialog box there is a page which generates a string, and sends it to a Java back end. This string contains spaces. Jquery is interpreting spaces as a click, causing my popup to close before it should. 
How would I make an event for cancel button that only gets fired on a mouse click, and not a space bar?

Code:

```
 $('<div id="popup">').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                      "Cancel" : {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            id: "cancelButton",
                            click: function(){
                            $('#popup').html('');
                            $('#popup').dialog('close');
                            }   
                        }, 
                    }
                });
var close = function (event, ui) {
            $('#popup').unbind("dialogclose", close);
                    //reload page
                };
            $('#popup').on("dialogclose", close);

            $('#popup').load("index.html").dialog('open');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how this string causes an action to be performed?

Comment: Perhaps with an event key code

Comment: What did you do to answer this question yourself the Jquery side has the answer under [events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/)